# jdeveloper 11g - how to enable primefaces autocomplete and tags

Tags: primefaces, jdeveloper

I need your help in enabling the autocomplete and primefaces tag in Jdeveloper11g. I have added the primefaces library in the class. However, when I tried to add the jar to project properties->JSP Tag libraries, it give me this error
"A valid Tag Library Descriptor (*.tld) was not found."

So can you please help to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of JSF is the prime faces component implementing? Dev 11g is still on JSF 1.2 - you can try JDev 12c which is JSF 2.

Beyond that have a look at the ADF Faces autosuggestBehavior tag as an alternative.
http://www.gebs.ro/blog/oracle/oracle-adf-form-autocomplete-using-autosuggest-behavior-search-view-add-edit/

Comment: The PrimeFaces 5.1 jar